# How to change the size of the view based off how many cells are in a UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am creating a collection view full of menu items. The collection view is supposed to be tall enough so that it fits perfectly in the size of view.

I can set the UICollectionView with a fixed height constraint, but if there are 20 items then that height might be too small or if there are 5 cells the height would be too big.

Is there a way to change the frames of the main view and the Collection view based off how many cells the view will have? Possibly in the viewDidLoad() function?

Answer (score 0):

set the height constraint of the collection view in storyboard with any value , and hook it as IBOutlet say `collectionHCon`

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    self.collectionHCon.constant = numberOfItems * itemHeight
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
}
```